# How to make JPanel stay onTop (on z-axis), using setLayout(null)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint, always-on-top

I have a JPanel named `Scene` which includes the following JPanels:
`Frame`, `Projector`, `Tools`.

I use null Layout on `Scene` because I want to use specific co-ordinates so no other Layout fits for me. I use the following code to add the 3 JPanels into the main JPanel `Scene`.

```
setLayout(null);
add(Tools);
add(Frame);
add(Projector);
```

I use this order because I want `Tools` to be always on top (on z-axis).

Now, if I do something inside the `Projector` that causes a repaint, then `Projector` comes on top of the other layers, hiding `Tools`. I can use a Thread to repaint the whole `Scene` JPanel but I see this "flash" when `Projector` comes onTop and goes onBottom and I dont want to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a good question, but more code would be helpful.

Comment: Specifically you need to create and post a [mcve]. Also, don't think that "no layout would work for me", as in all likelihood that is exactly what you need -- a decent working layout.... but hard to tell given the information posted so far.

Comment: What is the expected output??

Comment: Note that "on top" is also ambiguous. If you mean that it should be placed on the upper position of its container, then the container (here the scene JPanel -- note that variable names should start with a lower-case letter, so scene, not Scene) should use a BorderLayout, and the tools component should be added BorderLayout.PAGE_START. If by "on top" you mean that it should cover over other components, then you'll want to use a CardLayout to swap components or a JLayeredPane if you want to cover but show underlying components.

Comment: The expected output is the `tools` to be onTop of the other two JPanels. My code is more than 900lines of code, so I cannot just copy paste it, not even a part of it.. I can make a small program that simulates the problem but I think creating 3 JPanels is not that hard.

Comment: `"but I think creating 3 JPanels is not that hard"` -- I agree, and it's your question and your problem, so by all means, create your small program with 3 JPanels, and help us out here by posting it with your question. The onus of effort should be on **you** since 1) it's your question and 2) we're volunteers.

Comment: I did not demand anything so please do not get upset. I will make a tiny program to share. In advance let me say that what I want is `tools` to cover the other two JPanels. So maybe I will try JLayeredPane if it is something similar to JPanel.

Comment: Don't misread me -- I'm not upset, I'm just waiting on your code.

Comment: Don't use a JLayeredPane unless you want the other components showing through. If you want tools to cover and the others to be hidden, and then later swap tools for one of the others, then you really want to use a CardLayout.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is correct your question tends to be ambiguous because `on top` can  be interpreted as component should be placed on `NORTH` position or it can be interpreted as it should be appear top in `z axis` direction.

Comment: Tools are semi-transparent so I want other components showing through. so JLayeredPane is what I need right?

Comment: If that's the case, then yes, look into using JLayeredPane. You can specify precisely the z-order of components by using the `add(...)` method that takes an Integer constant as the 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to place components above each other in relation to their z-axis, then consider using a JLayeredPane as the main container, and then adding components using the `add(...)` method that takes an Integer as its second parameter. The bottom-most layer should be added using `JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER`, which I believe is 0. This will allow non-oqaque top components to show lower components through them.

Comment: still have to repaint the main container in order `tools` come ontop again

Comment: @GiannisTzagarakis: still need to create and post that [mcve] that demonstrates this issue for us. All I can do with regards to answer is to use what you've given us.

Comment: @GiannisTzagarakis Swing layouts are lazy by design, they allow you to add many components to a container without updating the container hierarcy or scheduling repaints until you tell it do so, that's just the way the API is designed

Comment: I made a small program with 4 JPanels and it's working just fine.. maybe java is joking me..

Comment: @GiannisTzagarakis: no, it just means that you've yet to isolate the bug. Keep adding code until the bug occurs.

Comment: I just repaint the the whole `scene` right after the caused repaint so I have no problem even with this "bad" solution